# Extracting part of line with using awk or sed

Tags: shell-script, awk, sed, cut

```
neterrore=connectionFailure&u=https%3A//data.com/callback%3Fcode%3DY6mOqlD2Cghcub29IlDKB7KHFuGCemVeoNr1lF5r6_c%26state%3DcDi00NM8gO8BImQwp1G0gmdIznygTwXQ&
```

In this string I need to extract between specific strings `code%3D` to  `c%26state`.

I need to get the output `DY6mOqlD2Cghcub29IlDKB7KHFuGCemVeoNr1lF5r6` from given that line.

Comment: Did you try to get your own approach to solve this task?

Comment: The first character of the result string is also included as the last character of the first delimiter string, and there's a dropped `_` before the final delimiter string. Please update your question to make the data consistent.

Answer (score 0):

This may help, assuming you need the string between code%3D and c%26state

```
 echo 'neterrore=connectionFailure&u=https%3A//data.com/callback%3Fcode%3DY6mOqlD2Cghcub29IlDKB7KHFuGCemVeoNr1lF5r6_c%26state%3DcDi00NM8gO8BImQwp1G0gmdIznygTwXQ&' | sed 's/.*code%3D\(.*\)c%26state.*/\1/'
```

Answer (score -1):

```
cat /tmp/testfile
"neterrore=connectionFailure&u=https%3A//data.com/callback%3Fcode%3DY6mOqlD2Cghcub29IlDKB7KHFuGCemVeoNr1lF5r6_c%26state%3DcDi00NM8gO8BImQwp1G0gmdIznygTwXQ&"  <-- ignore the ""

string=`awk -F% '{print $4}' /tmp/testfile`
O/P:3DY6mOqlD2Cghcub29IlDKB7KHFuGCemVeoNr1lF5r6_c

echo $string|  sed 's/^.\(.*\).\{2\}$/\1/'
O/P: DY6mOqlD2Cghcub29IlDKB7KHFuGCemVeoNr1lF5r6
```

Comment: wellcome to U&L I fixed formating, maybe you want to add some word explaining how sed and awk worked ?

Comment: I don't think it's safe to assume that the string is always after the 4th `%`.

Comment: Its a http response. the string will be there after 4th % and if not, then the resolution will be simpler and would be in line with what Dennis Jacob mentioned